# RPi.GPIO "flush" interrupts

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, interrupts

### Intro

It seems to me that when one adds and event detection, then removes it and the adds it again, something strange happen: 1) an event is removed to the "detection list"; 2) the event happens; 3) The event is added to the detection list; Result) The callback function is called immediately after 3) even if the event occurred while it was not detected

### In Details

My setup is the following:

- Raspberry Pi 2011.12 with archlinuxarm
- GPIO17: green led
- GPIO18: yellow led
- GPIO23: push button (pull up)
- GPIO24: door contact (closed when door is closed, pull up)

I want my RPI to be a door guard, in particular

- With the push button toggle between STATUS = 0 (non-armed) and STATUS = 1 (armed
- When in STATUS = 0 green led is on and yellow is off and the PI does not do anything
- When in STATUS = 1 green led is off and yellow is on and the PI print when the door is being opened or closed

My code is the following

```py
        import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
        from threading import Event
        import signal
        import sys

        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT, initial=0)
        GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT, initial=1)

        STATUS = False

        #When a door event occour:
        def door(channel):
                if GPIO.input(23):
                        print("The door has been opened!")
                else:
                        print("The door has been closed!")


        #When one pushes the button to toggle the sysyem
        def toggle(channel):
                global STATUS
                if STATUS:
                        GPIO.output(17,1)
                        GPIO.output(18,0)
                        GPIO.remove_event_detect(23)
                        STATUS = False
                else:
                        GPIO.output(18,1)
                        GPIO.output(17,0)
                        GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.BOTH, callback=door, bouncetime=300)
                        STATUS = True


        GPIO.add_event_detect(24, GPIO.FALLING, callback=toggle, bouncetime=300)

        #Cleanup function to gently close the system
        def cleanup(signum, frame):
                GPIO.cleanup()
                sys.exit(0)

        #to handle signals
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, cleanup)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, cleanup)

        #Wait forever
        Event().wait()
```

In particular, when one activate the system, an event detection is added both if the door is opened or closed. When one deactivate the system the detection of the event is removed

### The Problem

I have the following situation that I cannot understand:

- The system is armed
- The door is opened and closed several times; at the end the door is closed
- The system is un-armed
- The door is opened
- The system is armed again

Immediately after that I get an event "The door has been opened!". What I do not understand is my door has been opened *before* I armed the system. It seems that when I add the detection of the event again the RPi.GPIO remembers what happened when the detection was removed. The funny is that the problem is not symmetric: if I exchanged opening and closing events in the previous list, I do not get the message "The door has been closed!"

### QUESTION

Where am I wrong? Is there a way to "flush" the events while they are not added to the interrupt list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to be a feature of RPi.GPIO.  I would not try to fight it.

Perhaps change to something like the following.

```py
...

STATUS = False

#When a door event occour:
def door(channel):
   global STATUS
   if STATUS:
      if GPIO.input(23):
         print("The door has been opened!")
      else:
         print("The door has been closed!")

#When one pushes the button to toggle the sysyem
def toggle(channel):
   global STATUS
   if STATUS:
      GPIO.output(17,1)
      GPIO.output(18,0)
      STATUS = False
   else:
      GPIO.output(18,1)
      GPIO.output(17,0)
      STATUS = True

GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.BOTH, callback=door, bouncetime=300)
GPIO.add_event_detect(24, GPIO.FALLING, callback=toggle, bouncetime=300)

...
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However, as a good practice I think that it is better to keep the interrupt calls as low as possible.